# J Oliver EventStore V2.0 questions

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

I am embarking upon an implementation of a project using CQRS and intend to use the J Oliver EventStore V2.0 as my persistence engine for events.

1) In the documentation, ExampleUsage.cs uses 3 serializers in "BuildSerializer".  I presume this is just to show the flexibility of the deserialization process?

2) In the "Restart after failure" case where some events were not dispatched I believe I need startup code that invokes GetUndispatchedCommits() and then dispatch them, correct?

3) Again, in "ExampleUseage.cs" it would be useful if "TakeSnapshot" added the third event to the eventstore and then "LoadFromSnapShotForward" not only retrieve the most recent snapshot but also retrieved events that were post snapshot to simulate the rebuild of an aggregate.

4) I'm failing to see the use of retaining older snapshots.  Can you give a use case where they would be useful?

5) If I have a service that is handling receipt of commands and generation of events what is a suggested strategy for keeping track of the number of events since the last snapshot for a given aggregate.  I certainly don't want to invoke "GetStreamsToSnapshot" too often.

6) In the SqlPersistence.SqlDialects namespace the sql statement name is "GetStreamsRequiringSnaphots" rather than "GetStreamsRequiringSnapShots"

Comment: On Stackoverflow it is a good practice to ask one question per post. You'll end up with better answers because it is easier to post answers to one question, easier to upvote good answers, easier to find this post since you can give it a more descriptive title, etc. In any case, good questions!

Answer (score 3):

1) There are a few "base" serializers--such as the Binary, JSON, and BSON serializers.  The other two in the example--GZip/Compression and Encryption serializers are wrapping serializers and are only meant to modify what's already been serialized into a byte stream.  For the example, I'm just showing flexibility.  You don't have to encrypt if you don't want to.  In fact, I've got stuff running production that uses simple JSON which makes debugging very easy because everything is text.

2) The SynchronousDispatcher and AsychronousDispatcher implementations are both configured to query and find any undispatched commits.  You shouldn't have to do anything special.

3) Greg Young talked about how he used to "inline" his snapshots with the main event stream, but there were a number of optimistic concurrency and race conditions in high-performance systems that came up.  He therefore decided to move them "out of band".  I have followed this decision for many of the same reasons.

In addition snapshots are really a performance consideration when you have extrememly low SLAs.  If you have a stream with a few thousand events on it and you don't have low SLAs, why not just take the minimal performance hit instead of adding additional complexity into your system.  In other words, snapshots are "ancillary" concepts.  They're in the EventStore API, but they're an optional concept that should be considered for certain use cases.

4) Let's suppose you had an aggregate with tens of millions of events and you wanted to run a "what if" scenario from before your most recent snapshot.  It's a lot cheaper to go from another snapshot forward.  The really nice thing about snapshots being a secondary concept is that if you wanted to drop older snapshots you could and it wouldn't affect your system at all.

5) There is a method in each implementation of IPersistStreams called GetStreamsRequiringSnapshots.  You provide a threshold of 50, for example which finds all streams having 50 or more events since their last snapshot.  This can (and probably should) be done asynchronously from your normal processing.

6) "Snapshots" is the correct casing for that word.  Much like "website" used to be "Web site" but because of common usage it became "website".

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarity - #6 wasn't a comment on casing but instead pointing out a missing "S" in "Snaphots" versus "Snapshots" in the the SQL command.

Comment: And for #3, I wasn't clear enough in what I was asking.  I can see in the example of what it takes to query for the most recent snapshot for my aggregate.  What I was looking for was how to query the events that are stored after that snapshot so that I can replay them into the aggregate to bring it up to date.  I believe that is is the "GetFrom" at the level of persistence but I don't see where that functionality is available.  Shouldn't there be either an EventStore.GetFrom or a Stream.GetFrom" or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Okay, I fixed the typo in #6 and pushed the change.

Comment: To query for a snapshot forward, first load the snapshot (and then store it in memory indefinitely) and then call store.GetFrom(snapshot, int.MaxValue).  This will get you to the end of the stream.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, I don't see where store.GetFrom is defined (at least in the example code where the eventstore is an IStoreEvents).  I do see it in the OptimisticEventStore.  Perhaps a short discussion (?blog entry?) of the relations between EventStore & EventStore.Core projects and the underlying IStoreEvents and OptimisticEventStore is in order?

Comment: GetFrom is actually defined on each persistence engines, e.g. SqlPersistenceEngine, etc.  This is because the caller is accessing the commits in a non-traditional way.  Typically when you access a commit you do so with the intent to append additional events to the stream.  When you query for all events from a point in time, you're doing so with the intent to repopulate a view model, for example.