# JOliver EventStore - How to access all stored events?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

How can I access **all** stored events in the EventStore to rebuild my read models?

A method called `GetFrom` is mentioned at question [J Oliver EventStore V2.0 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353359/j-oliver-eventstore-v2-0-questions), but I cannot find this method on the interface "IStoreEvents" which is returned from Wireup.

Comment: NB in V6, this method is deprecated - there's a polling consumer with a placeholder not based on dates - which is a bad way of marking points of time and/or managing ordering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method is a part of the `IPersistStreams` interface and not the `IStoreEvents` interface.  The API needs to be refined slightly to accommodate that.  I have just added a method to `IStoreEvents` called `GetFrom(DateTime started)` that returns `IEnumerable<Commit>`:

https://github.com/joliver/EventStore/commit/1a039073df20fba11562c3c1a872180c225122c9

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for your immediate reply.